# JFX Print API, printing to a Brother QL 720NW

Tags: printing

I am implementing the JFX Printing API using Brother QL720NW Printer with the 62mm Wide Paper size, for some reason I get the "Bad Margins" Exception. How do I go round this here is the code:

```
try
{
    Printer printer = Printer.getDefaultPrinter();
    Paper photo = PrintHelper.createPaper("LabelPrinter", 62.0, 89.8, Units.MM);
    PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(photo,     PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE, Printer.MarginType.HARDWARE_MINIMUM);
    PrinterAttributes attr = printer.getPrinterAttributes();
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();
    double scaleX = pageLayout.getPrintableWidth() / node.getBoundsInParent().getWidth();
    double scaleY = pageLayout.getPrintableHeight() / node.getBoundsInParent().getHeight();
    Scale scale = new Scale(scaleX, scaleY);
    node.getTransforms().add(scale); 



JobSettings jobsettings = job.getJobSettings();
jobsettings.setPageLayout(pageLayout);        
    if (job != null) {
        boolean success = job.printPage(node);
        if (success) {
            job.endJob();
        }
    }    
node.getTransforms().remove(scale);


}      
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
```

The Node used to Print is a simple Label that I am using for testing purposes. After I get a print out then I will implement a bigger node to print exact parameters required.

Let me know if this code is ok. or needs some refactoring.

thanks in advance

Comment: Here is a link of someone that was facing the same problem - hopefully it might provide the clear picture of the problem at hand: https://www.java-forums.org/javafx/95904-illegalargumentexception-bad-margins-when-printing-dymo-labelwriter-450-a.html

Comment: looking inside the Printing API, there are some calculations that take place and the "Bad Margins originates from here" PageLayout.java the issue seems to be in the calculations. can anyone help on what happens with custom paper sizes?

Answer (score 0):

The Answer was in the printing settings of the actual printer for anyone seeking the answer here is a link for a solution:
https://forum.sambapos.com/t/how-to-change-the-printer-size-paper/10442/11